# Outlook web app for ios and dialog

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-app

When opening dialog from my add-in using Outlook Web App on iOS, I receive an error. In Windows the solution is to add the site as trusted but how do I do this in iOS?  The help link redirect to help for IE 11

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the domain to the [AppDomains](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/appdomain) section of your add-in's manifest file.

```
<AppDomains>
  <AppDomain>https://www.northwindtraders.com</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

Fixing this in your manifest should resolve this issue across every client. You shouldn't need separate manifests for each platform, add-ins are designed to be cross-platform by nature.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook on the Web for iOS and Android (any Mobile browsers) currently supports API Requirement Set 1.3 and `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync()` is in API Requirement set 1.4. Outlook on the Web in desktop browsers supports API Requirement set 1.5. It is a known issue that Outlook on the Web on mobile browsers is reporting the wrong requirement set support.

Answer (score 0):

Mark, I have configurated the AppDomain but the problem continue. When I try open the login dialog with Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync

[manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNug8.png)

The dialog is opened in safari but the addin in owa show the picture previous. The dialog after that send user and password should be closed but this not succedd.
I think this happens because of the message I have in the addin. In IE I happened this same but I could configure it with the help page, but in OWA for IOS I do not know how to do it

Comment: Stackoverflow is QandA resource, there is a question and answer(s). Your comment **is not the answer**. You should consider to modify (by click "edit") your question with additional information you may have or if this is specific to the answer of a person, write the comment to his answer. Once again this is not forum type of resource, but the public resource where other ppl may quickly find answer on similar question, you asked. Please help them to do this efficient.